# Can you please explain what this Haskell List Comprehension example do?

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I was dealing with some Haskell function examples But I didn't understand this particular function. Now the function is:

```
func [n] = n
func (n:ns) = func [n+x|x<-ns]
```

I know that this is a **list comprehension** and i also learned that the syntax of the list comprehensions is like this :

```
[return-expression | elem <- collection, predicate]
```

but i still couldn't figure how this function works and what does it do ? Can you please explain it?

Also sorry for my English.

Comment: Have you tried manually expanding, say, `func [1,3,5]`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes i tried variety of parameters.

Comment: So what have you not understood? For future questions, please show how you expanded this so we can spots misunderstandings / errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[n+x|x<-ns]` is the list obtained by adding `n` to every element of `ns`. It is equivalent to `map (+n) ns`.

Hence, we have, e.g. :

```
func [a,b,c,d] =
func [a+b,a+c,a+d] =
func [a+b+a+c,a+b+a+d] =
func [a+b+a+c+a+b+a+d] =
a+b+a+c+a+b+a+d
```